# A complex MySQL query for M2M relationship

Tags: mysql

For the sake of clarity, lets assume I have a table structure like this:

> | **word** | **filepath** |
>   `==============`
>   cat       | /usr/share/something.txt
>   cat       | /usr/share/anotherthing.txt
>   dog      | /usr/share/something.txt
>   car       | /usr/share/anotherthing.txt

What I want to do with this is, given a list of words, I want to get list of filepaths that every single one of those word exists in that file, for example, given a list of "cat,dog", I want to get "/usr/share/something.txt" but not "/usr/share/anotherthig.txt" because anotherthing.txt doesn't include word *dog* in it.

Comment: Do you include something because it matches *both* cat and dog, or *either* cat and dog? This is the inclusion case. The exclusion case is "where matches some other term" of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach that should work is just matching the group by count with number of words you are searching on.

```
SELECT filepath,count(*) c FROM table WHERE word IN ('cat','dog') GROUP BY filepath HAVING c=2
```

Answer (score 0):

This finds rows where

- *either* cat or dog matches
- filepath is not common with non cat/dog rows

Code:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable M1
WHERE
    M1.Word IN ('cat', 'dog')
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM
           MyTable M2
       WHERE
           M2.Word NOT IN ('cat', 'dog')
           AND
           M1.filepath = M2.filepath
           );
```